# What does the array flags attribute tell?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In a programming quiz I came accross the flags attribute for numpy arrays  in Python and I was wondering was the output all means. After reading https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html, I don't really understand some of the output. What do `C_CONTIGUOUS`, `F_CONTIGUOUS`, `ALIGNED` and `UPDATEIFCOPY` mean, explained without as much jargon as the documentation?

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([[3,4],[3,5]])
print(x.flags)
```

which outputs the following:

```
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Answer (score 1):

It gives information about how the array is stored in memory.

C_CONTIGUOUS true means it is stored as c-type in memory.

See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html) for more on each attribute.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to figure out what kind of information. I understand `OWNDATA` and `WRITABLE` and starting to understand `C_CONTIGUOUS` and `F_CONTIGUOUS` as well (but not why in a  higher dimensional array they can both be true).

Comment: @Femkemilene I guess it is because internally each dimension are stored separately. So on can be a c-type and the other a f-type.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. As far as I understand the arrays are always stored contiguous (so not seperately?), for C-contiguous the rows are stored next to each other, for F-contiguous the columns.. Would I be right to assume that the only way in which higher-dimensional arrays can be stored in the same way is that they only have one element in each dimension?

Comment: @Femkemilene you are right data is contiguous as detailed here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Comment: @Femkemilene it seems that it is only possible if `self.shape[k]=1`